# Microsoft SMSS - Joining tables on t2.primary key = t1.foreign_key

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I need to join two tables together to create a table with columns for employee id, employee name and their boss' name.

### The 'hier' table

[image: Hierarchy table]

### The 'employees' table

[image: Employees table]

The query I wrote is almost working, putting an employee name in the right spot, but not the right employee:

```
SELECT em.emp_id, em.emp_name, em.emp_name AS boss_name
FROM employees em
LEFT JOIN hier h ON (h.boss_id = em.emp_name)
```

Which outputs:

[image: The table I'm left with]

I need to have each person's boss to have the right name, and in the case of Big Boss, 'N/A'. Like so:

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: As you have hierarchical data you need to use a recursive CTE. There's quite a steep learning curve ahead for you.

Comment: Your current query is incorrect - joining `h.boss_id = em.emp_name` will give you zero meaningful results.

Comment: Hmmmm... why do you need any `JOIN` on `hier` table? I see a self join here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a self join with Employee table

```
SELECT em.emp_id, em.emp_name, e1.emp_name AS boss_name
FROM employees em
LEFT JOIN employees em1 ON em.boss_id = em1.emp_id
```